# how to edit the sizes of images/icons inside a button in xml android studio?

Tags: android, xml

I have tried using a downloaded image and putting it on my buttons but the size of the image is too big. I tried looking for smaller image but all of the images are big. So, I'll just have to edit the size of the image that I put in my button. Here's where I am so far.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOJmb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also getting this issue. I tried it with the static size of the button in my activity. Try with the static size of a button it will work for you.

Comment: Did you mean changing the size of the button itself or are you referring to a different solution?

Comment: Yes you can apply the static height and width of your button and set background into it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set an image as your button background, you can try this.

```
android:background="@drawable/your_button_name"/>
```